# How does ripples in dc affect working of a dc motor?

Tags: dc-motor

In the circuit provided here ,the supply voltage to the motor(+24 V ) is not a steady dc . It is the output of a full wave rectifier. how does it affect the working of a dc motor.?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given the inertial behavior of a typical motor, the ripple in supply will not cause significant adverse effect.

The most noticeable effect, for really large ripple factors, would be an audible buzz at the ripple frequency.

It is fairly common practice to provide unregulated DC to the motor drive line - **more efficient** than consuming some of the delivered power at a regulator.

---

***Edit:*** Clarifying based on comments:

- **Mechanical inertia**: A rotor with any non-trivial mass, once rotating, will continue to rotate even if a transient drop in Voltage occurs sometime within the cycle. Thus, the motor will not come to a halt or stutter noticeably due to ripple. The "stutter" that might occur on really poorly regulated power (*e.g. full wave rectifier with no reservoir caps*) will generate the audible buzz mentioned above, at twice line frequency
- **Electrical inertia**: Any inductance electrically behaves as an inertial element: It resists change, as mechanical inertia does. Thus, the coils of the motor concerned will themselves serve as a means of smoothing out the supply power. This is the reason very cost-sensitive designs tend to use smaller reservoir caps when driving an inductive load, compared to driving a non-inductive one.

Both these elements contribute to simplifying power feed design for conventional DC motors - so long as the line frequency and its first harmonic are not resonant with the motor's *rotation rate* or (*rotation rate* x *number of coils*). Resonant power ripple can tear apart a motor pretty quickly.

As indicated in comments by [Dave Tweed](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67879/how-does-ripples-in-dc-affect-working-of-a-dc-motor/67880?noredirect=1#comment130623_67880) and [Andy Aka](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67879/how-does-ripples-in-dc-affect-working-of-a-dc-motor/67880?noredirect=1#comment130595_67880), a *reactive* ripple reduction method i.e. a (bigger) capacitor as opposed to a linear regulator, will improve efficiency:

- For a current Ipeak, motor torque is proportional to average value `0.6366 x Ipeak` while resistive losses are proportional to RMS value `0.7071 x Ipeak`.
- For pure DC, these become equal, so efficiency is maximized.

Comment: Inertial behavior, and inductance of windings. Inductance in series smoothes ripples, like caps in parallel.

Comment: @Kaz "Inertial behavior, and inductance of windings ".what does this mean Kaz. You mean the ripples will have an effect on these?. If so ,how?

Comment: I can't speak for Anindo, but I would presume that intertial behavior refers to the moment of inertia (rotational inertia) of the rotor. Intertia is the tendency of a mass to resist acceleration. Moment of inertia is the tendency of a mass to resist angular acceleration. Inductance is a kind of "inertia" against a change in current. These work toward keeping the motor rotating smoothly even though the applied voltage fluctuates.

Comment: @raforanz Please see my view on inertia in the edit. The fault was mine: I tend to treat a system as an integrated black-box, with mechanical, electrical, optical and magnetic effects bundled into one, so if a single term covers the ground I'm too lazy to "componentize" it. Hopefully the edit makes things clearer.

Comment: The ripple will cause higher power losses and extra heat as well

Comment: Specific to @Andyaka's point: The motor torque will be proportional to the *average* value of the current (0.6366 x Ipeak), while the resistive losses will be proportional to the *RMS* value of the current (0.7071 x Ipeak). On pure DC, these values would be equal.